# Where do I get my reward for the Penguin's Cache side quest?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

At one point in Batman: Arkham Origins, you get a side quest to find all of Penguin's weapon caches that are hidden through the city. For every cache you find after the first, a message similar to this one is displayed:

[image]

Where is Penguin's Black Market? I don't see any waypoints on my map, and the case file for the Penguin is listed as Completed. I went through his base again, but it is completely deserted.

Comment: You probably didn't see the `ONLINE` part in `NEW ONLINE REWARD:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Penguin's Black Market is a multiplayer-only feature.  It allows you to purchase crates containing gear and other items for use online.

[image: mutiplayer menu]

When you enter the store, you will be greeted with notifications that you have some crates and are given the option to open them.  I don't think the items you get from the crates are predetermined, it appears to be random.

Comment: Well that's disappointing...